# How to I create a background in Kaboom.js

Tags: javascript, kaboom

So me and a friend are working a project out of boredom and we are having trouble figuring out how to make a background.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
kaboom({ background: [0, 0, 0] })
```

to change the background color.
[0, 0, 0] is the RGB code for black so the background would be black.

If you wanted the background to be red you would use:

```
kaboom({ background: [255, 0, 0] })
```

Hope this helped!